# Metodos estáticos externos não sendo reconhecidos no projeto

Tags: spring-boot, maven, java-8, static, library

Estou importando uma biblioteca de utils no meu projeto principal, a biblioteca atualmente contém um unico metodo estático, eu consigo importar tanto manualmente como pelo maven, porém não estou conseguindo acessar o metodo estático da biblioteca.
Estou usando Spring boot, maven e JDK 1.8 no projeto
a biblioteca foi criada com JDK 1.8.

Classe dentro do .jar:

```
import java.util.List;

public class CalculoGeografico {
    public CalculoGeografico() {
    }

public static boolean CalcularPontoDentroPoligono(List<Double> latidudes, List<Double> longitudes, Double pontoLatitude, Double pontoLongitude) {
    boolean result = false;
    int j = latidudes.size() - 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < latidudes.size(); j = i++) {
        if (((Double)latidudes.get(i) < pontoLatitude && (Double)latidudes.get(j) > pontoLatitude || (Double)latidudes.get(j) < pontoLatitude && (Double)latidudes.get(i) > pontoLatitude) && (Double)longitudes.get(i) + (pontoLatitude - (Double)latidudes.get(i)) / ((Double)latidudes.get(j) - (Double)latidudes.get(i)) * ((Double)longitudes.get(j) - (Double)longitudes.get(i)) < pontoLongitude) {
            result = !result;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Poderia postar o pom.xml do seu projeto "principal" e o pom.xml da biblioteca em questão? Além disso, poderia postar também a chamada de método que vc está tentando fazer?